# XAMPP and JavaServlet

Tags: javascript, servlets, connection, xampp

Community.
I have a JavaServlet. I let it run with XAMPP's tomcat and can access it with localhost:8080/MyProjectName/ServletName. 
I also have HTML files, which are in my XAMPP folder like index.html, so that I can reach those files with typing localhost in my browser.
The Problem is that I cant directly access from the index file to my servlet. How can I do that? For example, I want to access to the JavaServlet with a JavaScript. Is that possible? If not, then what can I do?